# Update rows from other rows

Tags: sql

how can i update this table (zz col):

```
 id      xx      yy     zz     n
----   -----   -----   ---  -----
1       AA      20      0     0
2       AA      10      0     1
3       AA      10      0     2
4       BB      45      0     0
5       BB      15      0     1
6       BB      15      0     2
7       BB      15      0     3
```

[zz = yy where n = 0]
To:

```
 id      xx      yy     zz     n
----   -----   -----   ---  -----
1       AA      20      20    0
2       AA      10      20    1
3       AA      10      20    2
4       BB      45      45    0
5       BB      15      45    1
6       BB      15      45    2
7       BB      15      45    3
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use actual code here, do you have an UPDATE statement that is failing or are you trying to change the table structure ?

Comment: Which DBMS  u r using? Oracle,SQL Server?? and what do u mean by zz is dependent on xx?

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablename set zz=yy where n=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
update tablename  
set a.zz=(select a.yy 
          from tablename a 
          where a.xx=tablename.xx and a.n=0)
```

Comment: Not say Tanks if it is right then give right mark and vote

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the same table to do your update.

```
UPDATE A1
SET A1.zz = A2.yy
from 
A AS A1
inner join A AS A2 ON A1.xx = A2.xx AND A2.n = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 UPDATE table1
 SET table1.zz= table2.xx 
 FROM table2
 JOIN table1
 ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try this way (not tested, but this should help you)

Your UPDATE statement needs to be a correlated update-- you need some key in A that tells you which row in B to go to in order to retrieve the new value. Your WHERE clause should also be an IN or an EXISTS since it needs to return multiple rows.

```
UPDATE table1 a 
SET    a.zz = (SELECT b.yy 
               FROM   table1 b 
               WHERE  b.n = 0 
                      AND a.id = b.id) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   table1 b 
               WHERE  a.id = b.id);
```

Assuming the join results in a key-preserved view, you could also

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.id, 
               a.yy oldval, 
               x.yy newval 
        FROM   table1 a, 
               (SELECT b.id, 
                       b.xx, 
                       b.yy 
                FROM   table1 b 
                WHERE  b.n = 0) x 
        WHERE  a.xx = x.xx) 
SET    oldval = newval;
```